# strange relationship to nsmanagedObject

Tags: core-data, relationship, nsmanagedobject

i have multiple  NSmanagedObject from the same entity ( we call PersonEntity).

This entity have a relationship "to-many" for another entity (we call BusinessEntity).

when i populate my store, i create the BusinessEntity managedObject.
After i add this BusinessEntity managedObject to my first PersonEntity managedObject.

```
[(Person *)entity1 addBusinessObject:businessEntity];
[(Person *)entity2 addBusinessObject:businessEntity];
```

the addBusinessObject function ( generate by XCode ) :

```
- (void)addBusinessObject:(NSManagedObject *)value {    
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"business" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"business"] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"business" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}
```

this work but only just after the populate.

If i save the store, only the relationShip between the entity1 and the businessEntity exist.

I have no relationShip between entity2 and businessEntity.

Really strange

PS: my two Entity are subclass of NSManagedObject for use with undefined property, and transient property.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which property of which entity is transient? Is the relationship between `PersonEntity` and `Business` entity reciprocal?

Comment: I have found a solution. a have add a reverse relationship, and now i'ts OK.

Comment: Reverse relationships are the default and are assumed. In fact, Xcode will warn you if don't have reciprocal relationships.

Comment: yes, but i have add toggle the **MOMC_NO_INVERSE_RELATIONSHIP_WARNINGS** to **YES** when i have start this project.
It's really stupid.

Comment: Hmmm, must be one of the "improvements" in Xcode4.

Answer (score 0):

On the apple documentation [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html)

i have read this important text :

> **Important:** You must define
>   many-to-many relationships in both
>   directions—that is, you must specify
>   two relationships, each being the
>   inverse of the other. You can’t just
>   define a to-many relationship in one
>   direction and try to use it as a
>   many-to-many. If you do, you will end
>   up with referential integrity
>   problems.

Now it's work